# Get all posts components props in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm moving my blog from Jekyll to NextJS and missing a feature to return all posts in one list.

From the official examples and other sources, I see that posts are written in markdown, and developers need to read a directory with posts, parse files, extract front matter, etc.

But I heavily use schema.org attributes, and all posts are written in pure HTML, I only replaced img elements with NextJS implementation.

So instead of using frontmatter, I renamed my posts' file extension to .js and rewrote its contents to this:

```
import Breadcrumbs from '/components/breadcrumbs';
import PostHeader from '/components/postheader';

export async function getStaticProps() {    
    return {
        props: { 
            title: "How to start investing",
            description: "How to start investing in 2022",
            published: "2021-08-01",
            modified: "2022-04-09",
            tags: ["investing", "how-to"]
        }
    }
}

export default function Post() {
    return <>       
        <Breadcrumbs />
        <article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/TechArticle">
            <PostHeader />
            <div>
                blah.. blah.. blah..
            </div>
        </article>
    </>
}
```

So is there a way to get Component props by given folder path or something like that without parsing files?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Are you asking about how to setup [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)?

Comment: No, I need some kind of dynamic import. I can go through a list of files, but can't find a way to dynamically import each js file to grab post props to build an index page with post excerpts and read more buttons.

Comment: Very unclear question. Are do you have 1 file for each post? Or 1 file with all posts that you export? We probably would need to see the repo or a very detailed explanation on what your plan is. You should really be using a CMS for content and metadata, most are free and very easy to implement. Just some rewriting of your app to get your meta/schema-data added properly.

Comment: I end up separating front matter from HTML files and converting them to js files, as this way I can use the built-in <Image> component for image optimization. Also, I had to move post metadata from a page front matter to a separate js file with a list of objects, where the key is a post slug. Not the best solution, but I didn't find a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing all posts in a simple javascript list

```
export default ([
    {
        title: "How to start investing",
        description: "How to start investing in 2022",
        published: "2021-08-01",
        modified: "2022-10-23",
        tags: ["investing", "how-to"],
        slug: "how-to-start-investing",
        img: "startinvesting",
        excerpt: `
            Post excertp text...
        `
    },
    {...}
])
```

and then importing it in GetStaticProps, filtering by post slug

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import posts from '../../../data/posts'
import Breadcrumbs from '../../../components/breadcrumbs'
import PostHeader from '../../../components/post-header'

export async function getStaticProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            ...posts.find(post => post.slug == 'how-to-start-investing')
        }
    }
}

export default function Post(props) {   
    return <>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
        Post text...
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';    

export default function Post(props) {
        return <>       
            <Breadcrumbs />
            <article itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/TechArticle">
                <PostHeader />
                <div>
                    <p>{props.title}</p>
                    <p>{props.description}</p>
                    <p>{props.published}</p>
                    <p>{props.modified}</p>
                    <p>{props.tags}</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </>
    }

ComponentName.prototype ={
  title: String,
  description:string,
  published: VarDate,
  modified: VarDate,
  tags:String
}
```

Comment: I thought it can resolved Your Issue

Comment: You didn't get what I'm asking for, the question is not about prop types. I will post my solution later.